# How the private and public variables in cpp are distinguished at machine level using the executable file?

Tags: c++, processor

we all have an idea about private and public variables in c++. Is there any mechanism to distinguish the private and public members at machine level ? 
If the data members are accessible by using the addresses of the members then why to use the private and public in c++ programming.

Comment: No. There is no way to ask "Is this variable private or public" at runtime, so there would be no point in having such a mechanism.

Comment: public/protected/private only exist at compile time.

Comment: Variables only exist at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

private and public in C++ are entirely compile-time concepts; they are not enforced in any way at runtime. Classes and their semantics are just blueprints to tell the compiler to lay data in memory in a certain manner; at runtime there's only bytes of data and code that accesses them with some given offsets.

> If the data members are accessible by using the addresses of the members then why to use the private and public in c++ programming.

There are two big misconceptions here; first of all, they *need* to be accessible through address even "from the outside", otherwise a class couldn't provide to its clients references to its private fields (also, it's not clear how inlining would work).<sup>1</sup>

But most importantly, C++ access control is ***not*** a security thing. The point of private and public is to establish a separation of interface and implementation detail (and thus helping the clients not to put the object in a logically inconsistent state, or relying on implementation details subject to change), not to make data unaccessible to untrusted code; code in your sources (or even just running in your process) is assumed not to be hostile.

After all, if I really wanted to access private data of some library I could just edit the header and add a `friend` declaration, or do a `#define private public`, or ([use some template trickery](https://bloglitb.blogspot.it/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html) to [access it legally](https://bloglitb.blogspot.it/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html).

---

1. Notice that this is just the first and most obvious example that comes to mind. Even if you could devise a mechanism to track addresses obtained from "the inside" of the class (which would pose a lot of other problems with the semantics of pointers), the standard downright mandates that any `T *` can be safely casted to `unsigned char *` and read as an array of `sizeof(T)` `unsigned char` (see C++11 §1.7 ¶1, §3.9 ¶4, §3.10 ¶10), so that puts the nail in the coffin to this kind of protection mechanism.